# Sum of a Finite Geometric series is hard for me to explain to my high school students. Is there a simple explanation?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am a high school math teacher who likes to understand the development and rationale behind formulas, albeit I am not a math expert by any means.

Could I get some help in trying to explain how the formaula for the sum of a finite geometric series actually can be derived?  I need a a rather simple explanation initially, so that I can grasp the essential nature of the formula.  Thanks for allowing me some space here.

Comment: Like $$(1-q)\sum_{k=0}^n q^k = \sum_{k=0}^n q^k - \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}q^k = 1 - q^{n+1}\,?$$

Comment: this has been answered a million billion times before elsewhere on the site

Comment: For a handout I used to use that may be appropriate, see the file titled "seq-and-series.pdf" that I posted [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6544585). For a more advanced treatment with applications, see the file titled "geom-growth.pdf" at the same place.

Answer (score 2):

How about $$s=a+ar+ar^2+\dots ar^n\\rs=ar+ar^2+ar^3+\dots ar^{n+1}\\(r-1)s=ar^{n+1}-a\\s=\frac{ar^{n+1}-a}{r-1}=a\frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Try with a proof wihout words:

http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Algebra/SequencesSquare.shtml

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you or your students are familiar with bases, but I like to think about it this way:

In base $10$, note that $$\begin{align}9+90&=99=100-1 \\ 9+90+900&=999=1000-1 \\ 9+\cdots +9000&=10000-1\end{align}$$ So in general it seems that $$9+\cdots +9\times10^n=10^{n+1}-1$$ Or in base $2$, we get $$\begin{align}1+10=&100-1 \\ 1+10+100=&1000-1 \\ \vdots\end{align}$$ So in general, for base $r$ it holds that $$(r-1)+r(r-1)+r^2(r-1)+\cdots r^n(r-1)=r^{n+1}-1$$ Therefore $$(r-1)(1+r+\cdots r^n)=r^{n+1}-1\implies 1+r+\cdots r^n=\frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}$$ If there is a constant in front, just factor it out to get $$a_0\frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}$$