# Why $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+...+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}=\frac{1-(\frac{1}{2})^n}{1-\frac{1}{2}}$ is true

Tags: sequences-and-series

I saw a proof and there they used this equation. I wonder, why this equation is always true. I thought about it for a really long time and I have no Idea

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/786796/42969

Comment: "I saw an proof and there they used this equation." What is the proof and where are "they" used this formula? That would give a satisfying context for this question.

Comment: The derivation is given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Derivation

Answer (score 3):

Refer to [Geometric Series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) $\sum_k r^k$ with $r=\frac12$.

You can see that it is always true for $r\neq1$ and it easy to be proved by

$$(1+r+\ldots+r^{n-1})(1-r)=1-r^n$$

let try to expand the LHS to see directly how it works.

Answer (score 2):

Proof by induction:

Base case: n = 1

$$1 = \frac{1 - (\frac{1}{2})^1 }{1 - \frac{1}{2}} \checkmark$$

Inductive Step:

Assume $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2}^i = \frac{2^n-1}{2^{n-1}}$$
(This is equivalent to your original statement)

then
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^i + \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{n} = \frac{2^n-1}{2^{n-1}}+ \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{n}$$

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^i = \frac{2^{n+1}-2 + 1}{2^n}$$

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^i = \frac{2^{n+1}-1}{2^n} \checkmark$$

Proof Without Words:
[image: Proof without words:]

Or:
[image: Alternative partial sum picture]

Answer (score 2):

1)$S_n=1+1/2+1/2^2+...1/2^{n-1};$

2)$(1/2)S_n=1/2+1/2^2+.....1/2^n;$

Subtract 1)-2):

$(1-(1/2))S_n= 1-1/2^n;$

$S_n=\dfrac{1-1/2^n}{1-1/2}.$

Answer (score 1):

In addition to proof via the method of calculating $S_n$ in a geometric sequence, you can also understand why it holds by simple observation.

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} = 1\color{blue}{+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+ ...+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}} = 1\color{blue}{+\frac{2^{n-1} - 1}{2^{n-1}}}$$

$$1+\frac{2^{n-1} - 1}{2^{n-1}} = 1+1-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} = 2-\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{n-1}$$

This is equivalent to the fraction given.

$$\frac{1-\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^n}{1-\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1-\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^n}{\frac{1}{2}} = 2\bigg(1-\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{n}\bigg) = 2-\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{n-1}$$

Of course, you can use the typical way of calculating $S_n$ in a geometric sequence as well.

$$S_n = \sum_{k = 1}^{n}u_1\cdot r^{k-1} = \frac{u_1\big(r^n-1\big)}{r-1}$$

In case you want to know how it’s derived...

$$\frac{u_1\big(r^n-1\big)}{r-1} = \frac{u_1(r-1)\big(r^{n-1}+r^{n-2}+…+r+1\big)}{r-1} = u_1\big(r^{n-1}+r^{n-2}+…+r+1\big)$$

Now, apply that to the following.

$$S_{n} = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} 1\cdot \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{k-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

For general $a<1$ and general positive integers $r$:

$(1+a+a^2+a^3 \ldots +a^r)(1-a) = 1-a^{r+1}$ [make sure you see why]. Thus, $(1+a+a^2+a^3 \ldots +a^r) = \frac{1-a^{r+1}}{1-a}$.

Put $a=1/2$ and $r=n-1$.

Comment: It works for $a > 1$ too. The only thing that doesn't work for $a>1$ is you can't make it into a convergent infinite series. The finite sums are all fine.